# App Keyboard Shortcuts Display Bug?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, system-settings, keybindings

I'm encountering what appears to be a bug in the display of ** > System Preferences > Keyboard: Shortcuts - App Shortcuts**.

The shortcuts are functional, but as you can see, their names randomly display as ellipses.

[image]

- The phenomenon seems random.  Quitting/reopening sys prefs will cause the badly displayed items to change.
- Adding or deleting items also causes the display problem to shift to other items.
- Selecting a name causes it to appear truncated.

As the prefs for keyboard shortcuts are stored all over the place, I'm unable to simply delete a .plist and try again, and given that I've got dozens of custom keyboard shortcuts, starting from scratch would be onerous.  I can replicate the problem in a fresh user account on the same system.

Obviously this isn't anything like fatal - the shortcuts work correctly - but working with them is insanely difficult.

I'm running macOS 10.13.4.

Comment: Is your question about whether this is a bug or not or how to work around it?

Comment: Yes to both questions.

Comment: I have recently run into a similar issue only mine are all missing from the display dialogue but they still seem to work. I am running 10.13.5