# macOS High Sierra - Custom App Shortcuts in System Preferences appear as "..."

Tags: macos, high-sierra, shortcut

I've upgraded to macOS High Sierra from OS X El Capitan and most of my custom app shortcuts now appear as **...**. When editing, it becomes a tiny input box, though the menu items are still there unchanged.

How do I recover the lost description text for them?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you add a new app shortcut does the issue arise with the new item?

Comment: Second one of these in a few days - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327171/app-keyboard-shortcuts-display-bug - no answers on the other yet.

Comment: @Josh I tried but later I open Sys Prefs it's roll back to "..." again.

Comment: Is it the same thing on other users?